# Catching the print of the function

Tags: r, lambda

I am using package `fda` in particular function `fRegress`. This function includes another function that is called `eigchk` and checks if coeffients matrix is singular.

Here is the function as the package owners (J. O. Ramsay, Giles Hooker, and Spencer Graves) wrote it.

```
eigchk <- function(Cmat) {

  #  check Cmat for singularity

  eigval <- eigen(Cmat)$values
  ncoef  <- length(eigval)
  if (eigval[ncoef] < 0) {
      neig <- min(length(eigval),10)
      cat("\nSmallest eigenvalues:\n")
      print(eigval[(ncoef-neig+1):ncoef])
      cat("\nLargest  eigenvalues:\n")
      print(eigval[1:neig])
      stop("Negative eigenvalue of coefficient matrix.")
  }
  if (eigval[ncoef] == 0) stop("Zero eigenvalue of coefficient matrix.")
  logcondition <- log10(eigval[1]) - log10(eigval[ncoef])
  if (logcondition > 12) {
      warning("Near singularity in coefficient matrix.")
      cat(paste("\nLog10 Eigenvalues range from\n",
                log10(eigval[ncoef])," to ",log10(eigval[1]),"\n"))
  }
}
```

As you can see last if condition checks if `logcondition` is bigger than 12 and prints then the ranges of eigenvalues.

The following code implements the useage of regularization with roughness pennalty. The code is taken from the book "Functional data analysis with R and Matlab".

```
annualprec = log10(apply(daily$precav,2,sum))
tempbasis =create.fourier.basis(c(0,365),65)
tempSmooth=smooth.basis(day.5,daily$tempav,tempbasis)
tempfd =tempSmooth$fd

templist = vector("list",2)
templist[[1]] = rep(1,35)
templist[[2]] = tempfd

conbasis = create.constant.basis(c(0,365))
betalist = vector("list",2)
betalist[[1]] = conbasis


SSE = sum((annualprec - mean(annualprec))^2)
Lcoef = c(0,(2*pi/365)^2,0)
harmaccelLfd = vec2Lfd(Lcoef, c(0,365))
betabasis = create.fourier.basis(c(0, 365), 35)
lambda = 10^12.5
betafdPar = fdPar(betabasis, harmaccelLfd, lambda)
betalist[[2]] = betafdPar

annPrecTemp = fRegress(annualprec, templist, betalist)
betaestlist2 = annPrecTemp$betaestlist
annualprechat2 = annPrecTemp$yhatfdobj

SSE1.2 = sum((annualprec-annualprechat2)^2)
RSQ2 = (SSE - SSE1.2)/SSE
Fratio2 = ((SSE-SSE1.2)/3.7)/(SSE1/30.3)

resid   = annualprec - annualprechat2
SigmaE. = sum(resid^2)/(35-annPrecTemp$df)
SigmaE  = SigmaE.*diag(rep(1,35))
y2cMap  = tempSmooth$y2cMap

stderrList = fRegress.stderr(annPrecTemp, y2cMap, SigmaE)

betafdPar = betaestlist2[[2]]
betafd    = betafdPar$fd
betastderrList = stderrList$betastderrlist
betastderrfd   = betastderrList[[2]]
```

As penalty factor the authors use certain `lambda`.
The following code implements the search for the appropriate `lambda.

```
loglam = seq(5,15,0.5)
nlam = length(loglam)
SSE.CV = matrix(0,nlam,1)
for (ilam in 1:nlam) {
    lambda = 10ˆloglam[ilam]
    betalisti = betalist
    betafdPar2 = betalisti[[2]]
    betafdPar2$lambda = lambda
    betalisti[[2]] = betafdPar2
    fRegi = fRegress.CV(annualprec, templist,
                betalisti)
    SSE.CV[ilam] = fRegi$SSE.CV
}
```

By changing the value of the `loglam` and cross validation I suppose to equaire the best `lambda`, yet if the length of the `loglam` is to big or its values lead the coefficient matrix to singulrity. I recieve the following message:

```
Log10 Eigenvalues range from
-5.44495317739048  to  6.78194912518214
```

Created by the function `eigchk` as I already have mentioned above.
Now my question is, are there any way to catch this so called warning? By catch I mean some function or method that warns me when this has happened and I could adjust the values of the `loglam`. Since there is no actual warning definition in the function beside this print of the message I ran out of ideas.

Thank you all a lot for your suggestions.

Comment: If that is a message, you can catch it with `tryCatch`, but I'm not sure what you want to do after that

Comment: @rawr My goal is a function that adjusts the values of the vector 'loglam' based on this print. But the problem is that this print is some kind of additional notice and not a real warning.

Answer (score 0):

By "catch the warning", if you mean, will alert you that there is a potential problem with `loglam`, then you might want to look at `try` and `tryCatch` functions. Then you can define the behavior you want implemented if any warning condition is satisfied.

If you just want to store the output of the warning (which might be assumed from the question title, but may not be what you want), then try looking into `capture.output`.

Comment: I have already looked at tryCatch function and if my understanding is right thos would be the case if my function had the warnung as output, but this print is some kind of additional notice that won't stop evalutions.